# Can I use yt-dlp to extract only one video info from a playlist?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

Here's my code using Python (simplified version):

```
import yt_dlp

YDL_OPTIONS = {
    'format': 'bestaudio*',
    'noplaylist': True,
}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
```

The problem comes up when the url directs to a playlist
(e.g. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb)

Here's the output:

```
[youtube:tab] PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb: Downloading webpage
[youtube:tab] PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb: Downloading API JSON with unavailable videos
[download] Downloading playlist: C++
[youtube:tab] playlist C++: Downloading 100 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 100
[youtube] 18c3MTX0PK0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 18c3MTX0PK0: Downloading android player API JSON
[download] Downloading video 2 of 100
[youtube] 1OsGXuNA5cc: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 1OsGXuNA5cc: Downloading android player API JSON
[download] Downloading video 3 of 100
[youtube] 1E_kBSka_ec: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 1E_kBSka_ec: Downloading android player API JSON
...
```

As you can see, the **'noplaylist'** option didn't work in this case.

Is there an option or function making `ydl` only extract one video info, for instance the first one, in the entire playlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> noplaylist: Download single video instead of a playlist if in doubt.

Source: [github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/5fb450a64c300056476cfef481b7b5377ff82d54/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py#L274)

What you shared with us isn't a playlist of a single video so, according to me, there isn't any doubt here.

You can request `yt_dlp` to treat only the first video of the playlist by adding `'playlist_items': '1'` to `YDL_OPTIONS`. Then the info concerning the video are in `info['entries'][0]`.